# .Net Remoting vs. WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, performance, remoting

I am working on a .Net website which is going to have 1000s of concurrent users.

I am thinking of keeping the business components on the app server and UI components on the web server. Database (MS SQL Server 2005) will be hosted on another server. I am planning to use the load balancing as well.

Given this, what's the best way of communication from web server to app server if I want to have the optimum application performance and scalability?

Comment: Check the answer of @ybo

Answer (score 18):

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx) a performance comparison between WCF and other communication technologies (including .Net remoting). The conclusion is : WCF is faster.

Answer (score 10):

.NET remoting is more or less 'deprecated', it has been dissolved into WCF. So it's not an either/or question. I suppose you should ask: what kind of WCF (binding) or whether there are other alternatives.

Comment: Do you have a source for that comment? None of the associated classes/methods have been marked [Obsolete], and I can't find any evidence that remoting has been associated with WCF in any way.

Comment: That is why I said "more or less", Remoting isn't removed (yet) and hence no official link. But take a look at activity (use the SO tags) or check some unofficial publications: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e2a67727-ca70-4f1f-b2af-dca4a79d4236/

Comment: Now there is a source for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

"This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)."

Answer (score 5):

We use net.tcp bindings with hardware load balancing on our high traffic sites.  It seems to work great and we haven't had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've a project using 2 application servers and 2 front-end servers plus load balance: No problem at all. Runs fast like a thought.

The other team on my company is working in the same infrastructure. They have lots of problems... specially security ones!